# MySQL sun columns only if the comlums contain 1

Tags: mysql

I am tring to construct a select query that sums the total of each column only if the column contains 1 (one).

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
UniqueID, 
SUM(
SeqID0101 + SeqID0102 + SeqID0103 + SeqID0104 + SeqID0105 + SeqID0106 + SeqID0107 + SeqID0108 + SeqID0109 + SeqID0110 +
SeqID0201 + SeqID0202 + SeqID0203 + 
SeqID0301 + SeqID0302+ SeqID0303 + SeqID0304 + 
SeqID0401 + SeqID0402 + SeqID0403 + SeqID0404 +
SeqID0501 + SeqID0502 + 
SeqID0601 + SeqID0602 + 
SeqID0701 + SeqID0702 + 
SeqID0801 + SeqID0802 + 
SeqID0901 + SeqID0902 + SeqID0903 +
SeqID1001 + SeqID1002 + SeqID1003 + SeqID1004)
WHERE  
(SeqID0101 = 1 OR SeqID0102 = 1 OR SeqID0103 = 1 OR SeqID0104 = 1 OR SeqID0105 = 1 OR SeqID0106 = 1 OR SeqID0107 = 1 OR SeqID0108 = 1 OR SeqID0109 = 1 OR SeqID0110 = 1 OR SeqID0201 = 1 OR SeqID0202 = 1 OR SeqID0203 = 1 OR SeqID0301 = 1 
OR SeqID0302 = 1 OR SeqID0303 = 1 OR SeqID0304 = 1 OR SeqID0401 = 1 OR SeqID0402 = 1 OR SeqID0403 = 1 OR SeqID0404 = 1 OR SeqID0501 = 1 OR SeqID0502 = 1 OR SeqID0601 = 1 OR SeqID0602 = 1 OR SeqID0701 = 1 OR  SeqID0702 = 1 OR SeqID0801 = 1 
OR SeqID0802 = 1  OR SeqID0901 = 1 OR SeqID0902 = 1 OR SeqID1001 = 1 OR SeqID1002 = 1 OR SeqID1003 = 1)
```

The issue I am having is, if a column contant 3, that 3 is getting included in the SUM total.

Am I doing this wrong and if so how should I construct the query.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Cheers.

Comment: If you know your columns will only contains 1s, why do you perform a SUM? The result can only be 36 (if I counted well). And your query should be `where SeqID0101 = 1 AND SeqID0102 = 1 AND..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text is a bit unclear, but you should be able to use this:

```
SELECT
   UniqueID,
   SUM(IF(SeqID0101 = 1, 1, 0)
       + IF(SeqID0102 = 1, 1, 0)
       ...
       + IF(SeqID1003 = 1, 1, 0))
FROM
   my_table
GROUP BY 
   UniqueID;
```